# Inequality $ \left|x\sin\frac{1}{x}-y\sin\frac{1}{y}\right|\leq\sqrt{2|x-y|} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

$ \forall x,y>0 $,  then 
$$ |x\sin\frac{1}{x}-y\sin\frac{1}{y}|\leq\sqrt 2\sqrt{|x-y|} $$

Is $\sqrt 2$ the minimum positive real number such that the inequality holds ?

I try to apply [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), but no success, $f'$ is unbounded near zero

A related problem can be found in *American Mathematical Monthly* 6(June-July 1941), pp. 413-414

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523297/how-prove-this-inequality-x-sin-frac1x-y-sin-frac1y2-sqrtx-y).

Comment: By considering the inverses of x and y, you will get rid of the singular behavior and obtain the well known sinc function.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest a strategy which I think would work.

First, I'd make the substitution $x\to1/x$, $y\to1/y$. The inequality becomes: $$
\frac{\sin (x)}{x}-\frac{\sin (y)}{y}\leq \sqrt{2 \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right)}$$
where I've dropped the absolute value for readability.
Now consider the [shape of the function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$. It's local extrema are progressively smaller; let's denote them with $x_i$. Hence if we have $y-x$ which is "big" we can always find a $z$ such that both $x$ and $z$ belong to the same $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ interval and $f[z]=f[y]$. Effectively this means that the LHS of the inequality stays the same but the RHS decreases.

This shows that it is enough to prove the inequality when both $x$ and $y$ belong to the same $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ interval - meaning they are close to each other.

In this case, *I guess*, you can successfully use the Taylor expansion of  $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ around $2k\pi$ with 4 terms and prove the inequality.